# Scanner for first, middle,lastname

Tags: java, regex, java.util.scanner

The following is the requirement:
i. If there is a first, middle, and last, only display the first and last name
ii. If there is a first and last, then display both first and last
iii. If there is only a first name, then just display it

I have the following code:

```
String fullName = "first middle last";
Scanner nameScanner = new Scanner(fullName);
nameScanner.findInLine(" ");
MatchResult result = nameScanner.match();
if(result.groupCount() > 2)
{   
System.out.println(result.group(1)+ " "+ result.group(3));
}
else
{
System.out.println(fullName);
}
```

When I try to run the code I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match result available
at java.util.Scanner.match(Unknown Source)
at com.assignment.RunAssignmentApp.main(RunAssignmentApp.java:48)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I think your findInLine argument needs some capture groups (pairs of parenthesis).

Comment: When I tried it, I didn't get an exception (but it just printed out `first middle last`).

Comment: The `MatchResult` will refer to the thing you searched for, i.e. the single space.  Groups are substrings of the entire matched string.  But the entire matched string is just `" "`.

Comment: What will you do with last names that contain spaces like "van de Puy"?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett A long time ago, I did write data entry software that tried to divide up names into first/middle/last, for printing badges at a convention.  Not only did it not work all the time for names like your example, it also had problems with Asians who put their surname first, and Spanish speakers who put their surname in the middle and their mother's maiden name last.  I think I eventually had to give the users a lot more control over how to divide the name, because there's really no way to do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`String` has a built in `split()`.

```
String fullName = "first middle last";
String[] names = fullName.split(" ");

switch(names.length) {
    case 3: // The string had three tokens. Print the first and last one.
        System.out.println(names[0] + names[2]);
        break;
    case 2: // The string had two tokens. Print both.
        System.out.println(names[0] + names[1]);
        break;
    case 1: // The string had one tokens. Print it.
        System.out.println(names[0]);
        break;
    default: // The string had less than one or greater than 3 tokens.
        System.out.println("You either have no name or a very long name!");
}
```

Comment: split() is missing a regex :)

Comment: @AWT Oh noooooooo. I could have sworn that split() worked on whitespace by default. Corrected!

Answer (score 1):

Scanner doesn't work this way.  The way you're writing this, you would be better of splitting the input into string arrays based on the spaces:

```
public static void nameScanner() {
    String fullName = "first middle last";
    String[] names = fullName.split(" "); // split the string at the spaces
    if (names.length > 2) {
        System.out.println(names[0] + " " + names[2]); // arrays start at index 0, so names[0] is first name
    } else {
        System.out.println(fullName);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're taking input from a user, you definitely want to add some error checking and handling to make sure you don't go out of bounds on your array.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
nameScanner.findInLine("(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+)");
```

Comment: I'd recommend putting a `+` after each of the spaces.